# Applying XML cross apply to get data from XML file

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, store, cross-apply

I am applying XML cross apply to extract data from XML project file having multiple nodes by using Stored procedure.
**Stored Procedure is as follow**

```
INSERT INTO UCDetails
SELECT 
Usecase.value('@UserID','VARCHAR(100)') AS UCId, --ATTRIBUTE 
Usecase.value('@Name','VARCHAR(100)') AS UCName, --ATTRIBUTE 
Usecase.value('@PmAuthor','VARCHAR(100)') AS UCActor, --ATTRIBUTE 
UCPrecon.value('@Value','VARCHAR(MAX)') AS UCPre, --ATTRIBUTE 
UCPostcon.value('@Value','VARCHAR(MAX)') AS UCPost, --ATTRIBUTE 


FROM
@xml.nodes('/Project/Models/UseCase')AS TAB(Usecase) OUTER  
apply @xml.nodes('/Project/Models/UseCase/TaggedValues/TaggedValueContainer/ModelChildren/TaggedValue[5] ')AS TAB1(UCPrecon)OUTER  
apply @xml.nodes('/Project/Models/UseCase/TaggedValues/TaggedValueContainer/ModelChildren/TaggedValue[6]')AS TAB2(UCPostcon)

END
```

Instead of getting only a single row of data I am getting cross multiplication row as shown below

```
UCId            UCName           UCActor         UCPre                  UCPost        
UC01         Login            Bilal Haider    User must be Registerd User is Loggined sucessfully      

UC01            Login            Bilal Haider    User must be Registerd User is added   

UC01            Login            Bilal Haider    User is Loggined sucessfully   User is Loggined sucessfully    

UC01            Login            Bilal Haider    User is Loggined sucessfully   User is added   

UC02            Add User         Bilal Haider    User must be Registerd  User is Loggined sucessfully   

UC02            Add User         Bilal Haider    User must be Registerd  User is added  

UC02            Add User         Bilal Haider    User is Loggined sucessfully   User is Loggined sucessfully    

UC02         Add User         Bilal Haider    User is Loggined sucessfully   User is added
```

Sorry for posting the result like this
Correct rows are highlighted in bold, but Why I am getting all the other rows ?

XML File link:
[XML FILE](https://www.mediafire.com/?g2ad95t3bbhvzdh)

Comment: can you post the `xml file` and `expected output`

Comment: Dear How can I attach XML file ? kindly guide and expected output is highlighted in above table with bold

Comment: Dear  I have posted the XML file   https://www.mediafire.com/?g2ad95t3bbhvzdh you can download it from this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use cross apply against `TaggedValues`. Specify the xPath in the values clause instead.

```
select T.X.value('@UserID', 'varchar(100)'),
       T.X.value('@Name', 'varchar(100)'),
       T.X.value('@PmAuthor', 'varchar(100)'),
       T.X.value('(TaggedValues/TaggedValueContainer/ModelChildren/TaggedValue)[5]/@Value', 'varchar(max)'),
       T.X.value('(TaggedValues/TaggedValueContainer/ModelChildren/TaggedValue)[6]/@Value', 'varchar(max)')
from @xml.nodes('/Project/Models/UseCase') as T(X)
```

Result

```
------ ---------- ------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
UC01   Login      Bilal Haider  User must be Registerd         User is Loggined sucessfully
UC02   Add User   Bilal Haider  User is Loggined sucessfully   User is added
```

Comment: How can I make a sql statement which matches the above table Post condition with Pre condition of other Use cases ?

Comment: @BILALHAIDER You should ask a new question on the site where you describe what you want, what you have tried and how that is not working out for you.